# Super slow speeds between Windows 10 (Asus XG-C100C) and Mikrotik CSS326-24G-2S+RM

Tags: windows-10, networking, switch, 10gbit

Windows 10 with last updates
Asus XG-C100C (Aquantia AQtion AQC107) with last driver and last firmware
Mikrotik CSS326-24G-2S+RM with last update and last firmware

Connection scheme: Windows 10 -> Mikrotik -> Internet

I always get about 5 Mbps (from 1 to 7) download speed and 300 Mbps (good) upload speed at speedtest.net
Several years ago this setup was working correctly, when I tried.

What I tried:

1. Tweak almost all settings of Asus XG-C100C
2. Use different cables: Cat5, Cat5e, Cat6
3. Connect to different ports at 1Gbut speed
4. Insert Mikrotik S+RJ10 SFP into CRS326 and connect at 10Gbit speed
5. Insert Asus XG-C100C into a different Windows 10 computer

What resolves issue (and results in 300 Mbit upload and download speed at speedtest.net):

1. Use integrated networking card (at 1Gbps) instead of Asus XG-C100C
2. Use D-link DGE-562T (at 2.5Gbps) instead of Asus XG-C100C

Could you please recommend how to debug and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the "Recv Segment Coalescing (IPv4)" and problem fixed.

https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?106476-Aquantia-10Gbe-fix-by-disabling-one-advanced-setting-on-the-chip-thru-device-manager!